# VBA excel Rnd syntax

Tags: vba, excel

I understand the basis of Rnd function but don't understand here why the number that times Rnd is negative. Could anyone help please

```
Range("A1")=Formatcurrency(1-2*Rnd,2)
```

Comment: If the random number was greater than 0.5, then 2 * that number will be greater than 1, and 1 - a number greater than 1 is negative.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: the number that is multiplying the _Rnd_ is positive (+2). it is the same as `1 - ( 2 * Rnd )`

Comment: Right, i got it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not always negative. But in general, when you are wondering about something in VBA, make a small sampe and print it. Like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestMe()

    Dim lngCount    As Long

    For lngCount = 1 To 5
        Debug.Print "----------------"
        Debug.Print Rnd
        Debug.Print 1 - 2 * Rnd
        Debug.Print "----------------"
    Next lngCount

End Sub
```

It shows randomly the following:

```
----------------
 0.5137375 
 7.403994E-02 
----------------
----------------
 0.3534727 
 0.1903317 
----------------
----------------
 0.2697316 
 0.888813 
----------------
----------------
 0.2438452 
-0.9581559 
----------------
----------------
 6.091624E-02 
 0.2194171 
----------------
```

Thus, you can trace it to check the reason for the negativity. And stay positive :)

Comment: Thanks, that is really useful

Answer (score 0):

(1-(2*rnd),2) I think this is an order of operations issue you get rand value multiple it by 2 then subtract it from one.

the value will not always be less than 0 but has a good chance of it.

Might be able to help you accomplish your task if you're more specific as to what you're trying to do.